# Ruby code looping infinitely

Tags: ruby

```
class Triplet
    def initialize(array,sum)
        @array = array.sort()
        @array_size = array.size()
        @sum = sum
        @result = []
    end

    def get_triplet
      @array[0..-3].each_with_index do |arr, ind|
        pointer_one = ind + 1
        pointer_two = @array_size - 1
        while (pointer_one < pointer_two)
          temp_sum = @array[pointer_one] + @array[pointer_two] + arr
          if(temp_sum == @sum)
            @result.push([@array[pointer_one], @array[pointer_two], arr])
          elsif temp_sum < @sum
            pointer_one = pointer_one +1
          else
            pointer_two = pointer_two -1
          end
        end
      end
    end

    def get_result
      @result.each do |res|
        puts res
      end
    end
end

puts "Enter the array of numbers"
array = gets.chomp
array = array.split(' ')
array_integer = array.map{|a| a.to_i}
puts array_integer
puts "Enter the sum"
sum = gets.chomp
puts sum
t1 = Triplet.new(array_integer,sum.to_i)
t1.get_triplet
t1.get_result
```

Can anyone suggest me the fix so that it doesn't loop infinitly. It is program to find triplet in array whose sum is @sum. Its  looping in get_triplet method. Initialize method sets the array,array size. get_triplet method should store all three number whose sum is @sum in result array.

Comment: Any time that `temp_sum == @sum`, you'll get stuck in a loop, because neither pointer_one nor pointer_two will change any further. Thus, pointer_one will always be less than pointer_two, and it will always find that temp_sum == @sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a tangle of code like this is a sign something's not right, and in this case the source of the problem is not knowing about the [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) method. Here's a functionally equivalent solution:

```
def triplet(list, target)
  list.combination(3).find do |a,b,c|
    a + b + c == target
  end
end
```

For example:

```
arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]

p triplet(arr, 6)
# => [1, 2, 3]

p triplet(arr, 4)
# => nil

p triplet(arr, 10)
# => [1, 2, 7]
```

The algorithm used in your code looks problematic, or at least implemented incorrectly, and is also strictly limited to triplets. This code is far more generic and uses a proven, tested algorithm, so it's probably better suited to solving your particular problem.